# Change the text of a td based on its content in SharePoint 2013 (XSLT)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have web part showing a data view, in in which of the columns get its value like this:

```
<td>
 <xsl:value-of select="@Closing_x0020_Date"/>
</td>
```

This works just fine, but now the data that is being provided contains some "Null" values (the actual word Null). I'm trying to figure out a way that when the value equals Null, the cell should not show any text at all, but when it contains a date it show the value as it is.

This is what I tried, and of course, is not working:

```
<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Closing_x0020_Date = 'Null'">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:value-of select="@Closing_x0020_Date"/>
             </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<xsl:when test="@Closing_x0020_Date = ''">
```

Comment: Thanks @Thales but I tried that already, and it didn't work.

Comment: When you go in the allitems of your list (/List/NameList/allitems.aspx), the field "@Closing_x0020_Date" is returning a blank field?

Answer (score 0):

After all, I found a solution that worked. I want to post it here just in case it helps somebody else.

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@Closing_x0020_Date = 'Null'">
    <td class="ms-vb"></td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <td class="ms-vb">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Closing_x0020_Date" />
    </td>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

My mistake was that I was running the condition inside the `td` itself, instead I should have place it inside the `<xsl:choose>`. Thanks to those that look into it, specially @Thales.